# Sharing Gravity Forms among multisites

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, multisite

Disclaimer: I am a total noob in this.

I have a wordpress with multisite: German and English.

I have 10+ gravity forms (!) on the English site, and I wish to use the forms on the German site.

May I ask You to point me to a tutorial on how can i share the existing gravity forms on English web page among other pages in multisites?

I really do not want to recreate the forms from scratch and then maintain them.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Gravity Forms has a handy import/export function, so you would not really need to re-create all the forms as you can just export from one site and import to the other

Comment: @Und3rTow sounds like a good lead! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**You can't** use the same gravity form on different sites for your multisite configuration. You will have to install the plugins for all the sites and also create the forms separately.

Also, you should check gravity form licensing. For multisite configuration in WordPress, each installation on a site in the network is considered as one installation. So you should accordingly buy either business license or developer license.